# Error occurred during DocuSign API and Integration and Envelope Creation #DocuSignAPI

Tags: api, docusignapi, envelope

I am getting an error while creating Envelope using following code. But authentication is successful and I am able to retrieve Account Id.

Authentication code:

```
string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + Username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + Password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + IntegratorKey + "\"}";
cfg.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(cfg);
```

Envelope Creation code Code:

```
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(AccountId, envDef);
```

Error details:

```
A first chance exception of type 'DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException' occurred in DocuSign.eSign.dll

Error: Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}
```

---

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED" is the first failure before even the body is read, it means the Integrator Key is NOT valid for the environment, method call "Reserved" or Missing as the "message" states.

Most of the time this happens in a functioning system with the Integrator Key is "Turned off" if the system is doing something not allowed aka stuck in a loop of making a "reserved" call. If you have been testing and now went live in prod, it means your Integrator Key is NOT allowed in Production.

To help you the best way is to capture exact JSON/SOAP request posted by your API calls via Java to DocuSign by following steps explained at this DocuSign support article https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Please post these and what actual DocuSign API call you are trying to make and I am sure it will be we will be able to deduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you @David, Once authenticated, DocuSign provides my profile details as response. For Authentication i sent same Integrator Key and it's successfully authenticated. Currently I'm using Development account.Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @ShreeKrishnaKumarD you are welcome and I have added more to the answer to move us along in identifying your real issues, which may be a code logic issue on the "status code" returned aka a false positive, etc. So please add your "intent" aka code / API call and what you capture from DocuSign Logs.